# How Firebase Auth UID is generated?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I use custom authentication using JWT Token.

The login process is like this:

1. The user input his/her phone number
2. They will get SMS confirmation containing 4-digit-code that they need to enter
3. The user enter the digits, and the verification success. The app now is processing the login.
4. Mobile app request a JWT Token from our server, the server combine `phoneNumber` into the token.
5. After getting the token, it uses  `FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithCustomToken(customToken)`
6. In the Firebase rules, `auth` is no longer null, and it contains `uid` and `phoneNumber`

---

#### The Questions

**1. How the `auth.uid` is generated? Is `auth.uid` generated from the device UID? I mean if the user change their device, the `auth.uid` will no longer valid?**

In the firebase rules,

```
"users": {
  "$user_id": {
    ".write": "$user_id === auth.uid"
  }
}
```

If the `auth.uid` changes between devices, the user will no longer have access to the data if they change the their device (even when they use same phone number).

**2. Should I use this instead?**

```
"users": {
  "$user_id": {
    ".write": "data.val().phoneNumber === auth.phoneNumber"
  }
}
```

Comment: When you mint a custom token, you pass in the `uid`. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/server/create-custom-tokens. It is important to use a uid that you can consistently recreate for that user.

Comment: That helps a lot, One last question, for future sake, in case of user changing their phone number, what do you recommend to put as uid? Thanks.

Comment: This is one of the reasons Firebase Authentication providers use a UUID and not some hash of for example the email address: by removing all meaning from the uid itself, it is not dependent on any underlying properties and those properties can freely change.